# Design to link two model classes with different multiplicity

Tags: design-patterns, domain-model

It is usually well known how to deal with model classes that have a 1:N relationship: classical examples are order->items or client->orders.

Every layer of the software has its appropriate and typical solution: a sort of prepared template. Again, the same classical example: a GUI of an order where the user can enter a grid of products. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume we're exactly in this situation, with a software already developed (i.e. a windows universal app).

Now I'm asked to introduce a change, a sort of relation from 1 product to M orders. Is there any standard way to achieve this goal or any good suggestion to minimize the rework? A few more details to clarify. The user is filling an order with many products, but - in certain special cases  - he wants to reuse the same product already entered in another order because he considers those "partial" orders as a whole one...
Of course, I've oversimplified the real requirement: it is really a "batch" and not a product and its code should be unique. The quantities of those linked orders should be added up and compared to the sum of the quantities in the batches. At this point I'm also striving to figure it out how to visually represent it.

What's the correct approach to find a fast solution?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking.  It sounds like your users are placing orders and want to re-use a previous order as a template.  Is that correct?

Comment: You're right. First of all "my" request is unclear. Ok, users are placing orders and want to group similar (almost identical) orders together... Basically it's like they have 2 orders for 20 and 2 for 30, so 4 orders for a total of 100. And they need to insert 3 batches of 20, 30, 50. It's just an example. And what is missing in the current app is the possibility to group those orders...

Comment: Instead of giving us simplified examples and abstractions can you give us the *real* requirements?  I think some key concepts are being lost in your simplifications.

Comment: My previous comment goes in that direction. The only things I'm skipping are the specific business definitions (but I'm confident that if I say we're selling orders of apples and managing lots/batches of red or yellow apples, the software solution can be described the same as well). Let me add other details: I've develop an integrated package showing to the users a grid of orders (with counterparty, qty, delivery, etc). Users select an order (one, this is the limitation) and thus they open the detail view of that order where they can insert a grid of batches (red, yellow..) with tot qty checks

Comment: Oh... and grouping some different orders together managing the detail view for the group instead of a single order appears to me as a complex and non standard request (with non trivial consistency checks): my question is - do you agree with me or do you recognize the request pattern as a standard one with a known implementation design (a sort of software template, like the master detail view I've realized in the current app).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to do a slight variation on the master-detail template.
In the master view, I'm adding a context menu for each row

```
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Open MultiOrder" Click="MultiOrder_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add to MultiOrder" Click="MultiOrder_Add" />
```

It will open (toggle visibility of) a vertical sliding menu overlapping the grid

```
void MultiOrder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Model.Order order = header_orders.SelectedItem as Model.Order;
    var groupVM = Model.OrderGroup.GetGroup(order.order_num,order.order_item_num);

    MultiOrderSlide.DataContext = groupVM;
    MultiOrderSlide.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

The objective is to manage the "third" dimension of the master order grid: creating a new group of items, adding new items to the group (or ungroup it).

Of course, this implies similar (and more complex) changes in the detail view: presenting the datagrid of the group of the items (plus a "total") and raising all the property changed in order to update the detail view with the projection for the selected group item (or the total).